# raspberry piでLANケーブルを抜くとwifiが使えない

Tags: raspberry-pi, network

初めまして。
USBのwifiアダプタを使って、raspberry piに無線LANでSSH接続しようと試みていますが、以下の事象で困っております。
何か思い当たることがおありでしたら、ご教示ください。

- 事象
  無線LANと有線LANの両方が稼働しているraspberry piで、LANケーブルを抜く（刺さない）と無線LANも機能しない
- 環境

  - raspberry pi model B+（電源はiPhone用ACアダプタから供給）
  - OS:raspbian 2014-09-09
  - カメラモジュール、I2C有効（ただしなにも接続せず）
  - wifiアダプタ：WLI-UC-GNM2/GW-USNano2
  - LANルータ（DHCP）：WHR-G301N(WPA2-PSK/AES)
  - Mac book AirからSSHでログインして操作
- 事象が発生する状況

  1. 有線LAN接続でSSHログイン
  2. lsusbでwifiアダプタは認識されており、ifconfigでもwlan0として認識
  3. /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.confを設定し、ifup
     →dncpでIPを取得でき、そのIPに対するSSHログインも成功（有線LAN側も使える）
  4. (3)状態で一旦shutdownしてLANケーブルを抜き、再起動する
     →ルータ管理画面上ではIPが振られていることが分かるが、そのIPに対するSSHログインはできない
  5. (3)状態でSSHをログアウト（起動したまま）し、LANケーブルを抜いても(4)と同様
  6. (4)or(5)状態でLANケーブルを挿し、wifiアダプタを抜くと(1)同様にログイン可能で、
     　　　wifiアダプタを挿して(2)に戻るとwifiも使える

wifiアダプタを２種類書いていますが、上記事象はどちらでも発生します。
`/etc/network/interfaces`および`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`の記載内容については、
いろいろなサイト・ブログを参考にかなり試しましたが、状況は改善していません。
`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`を使わない設定でも同じでした。

VNC経由でGUIツールのwpa_guiを使うことも試みましたが、こちらではwlan0が認識されず、使えない状態です。
(chmod 4755でwpa_guiのパーミッションを変更すれば良いというブログ記事も拝見しましたが、それを行うとwpa_guiのウィンドウになにも表示されなくなりました）

という訳で、なぜかLANケーブルとセットでないとwifiが機能せず、困っております。
お知恵を拝借できると幸いです。

**12/20追記**
みなさんご回答とコメントありがとうございます。
上記3.の状態で、2つのIPに対してMacからpingを打ちwlan0,eth0それぞれでtcpdumpを取ったところ、wlan0の方ではecho requestも見えませんでした。（eth0には両方のIPについてecho request/replyが見えている）
キャプチャ結果でラズパイ側が"ホスト名.local"と表示されており、avahi-daemonが悪さをしているのでしょうか。。。

なお、上記3.の状態での/etc/network/interfacesとwpa_supplicant.confは下記です。

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
  ssid="SSID"
  psk=パスキー(16進)
  auth_alg=OPEN
  scan_ssid=1
}
```

**12/22追記**
皆さん引き続きお付き合いありがとうございます。
Taichi Yanagiyaさんご指摘の/proc/net/arpの値（raspberry pi）は下記となっていました。IP..11.4がmac、..11.3はiPad（SSH端末アプリ）、..11.1はルーターです。

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.11.1     0x1         0x2         00:24:a5:b7:2f:4f     *        wlan0
192.168.11.3     0x1         0x2         70:11:24:4b:1e:dd     *        wlan0
192.168.11.4     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.11.3     0x1         0x2         70:11:24:4b:1e:dd     *        eth0
192.168.11.4     0x1         0x2         48:d7:05:b7:6b:ed     *        Ethan
```

**12/23追記（解決）**
皆様ご回答とコメントありがとうございます。
Yanagiyaさんご指摘の方法とは少し違いますが、クライアント側で「arp -d」コマンドで問題のIPのキャッシュを削除し、クライアントを再起動したところ問題が解消しました。
（なんとなくやっていたら治ってしまい、記録を取っていなくてすみません）

12/22追記ではYanagiyaさんのご指摘を勘違いしておりました。上記Ras-PiのARPテーブルは関係ありませんでした。
ARP以外にも、今まで深く考えていなかった点についてご助言をいただき、誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: ラズパイにはディスプレイはつないでないんですか？有線外しているときは外側からのアプローチだけに見えますが。

Comment: @flied onion
コメントありがとうございます。ディスプレイは繋いでいません。単に所有していないからですが、これを機に購入するつもりです。

Comment: 了解です。さしあたり確認したい事があれば、cronしこんでどこかにテキスト書き出しておく手はあるかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wlan0、有線LAN I/F (仮に eth0)が同じネットワークセグメントにあるのではないでしょうか。

一般的な Linux のルーティングは、宛先によって outbound の I/F が決まります。
宛先(ネットワークアドレスやデフォルト)に対し、wlan0, eht0 の 2つのルーティングが設定(ip route show コマンドや route コマンドで確認)されていても eth0 が先になっていれば、eth0 からしか出ていきません。

もし、そうならば、以下のような経路になります。

- 行き: SSHクライアント → wlan0 → sshd
- 戻り: sshd → (ルーティングテーブル参照) eth0 → SSHクライアント

有線LAN のケーブルを抜いても I/F の設定は残っていればルーティングテーブルも残ります。

wlan0 に届いたパケットの戻りを wlan0 から出したい場合は、ソースルーティング(ソースポリシールーティング)を設定する必要があります。

(設定例)

```
eth0  の IPアドレス: 192.168.0.10/24
wlan0 の IPアドレス: 192.168.0.20/24

ip rule add from 192.168.0.10 table 1
ip rule add from 192.168.0.20 table 2
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.10 table 1
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table 1
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 src 192.168.0.20 table 2
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table 2
```

設定の意味は、"ip rule" "ソースルーティング" などで検索してください。

他、ARP 関係の問題もあるかもしれません。
キーワード: rp_filter, arp_announce, arp_ignore

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘通り、ip ruleのmainテーブルはeth0が先になってました。例示いただいた内容でip rule/routeを設定してみたところ、質問文3.の状態でもwlan0には疎通しなくなりました。
ARP関係はこれから調べさせていただきます。

Comment: tcpdump の結果から、ARP の問題と思われます。
SSHクライアントが Linux であれば cat /proc/net/arp で 2つの IPアドレスに対し同じ MACアドレスとなっていると思います。

設定例:

    # echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_announce
    # echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_ignore

    OS起動時にも有効にするなら、 

    # vi /etc/sysctl.conf
    net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 2
    net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 1

(↑整形されるでしょうか...)

Comment: ありがとうございます。問題を指摘いただいている設定値はRas-Pi側で良かったでしょうか？Ras-Piでのcat /proc/net/arpの値を質問本文に追記しました。

Comment: あ、いえ、クライアント側の ARPテーブルを知りたかったのです。Ras-Pi 側の /proc/net/arp はこれで問題ありません。Ras-Pi からクライアントへの戻りパケットについてはソールルーティングで解決、クライアントから Ras-Pi への ARP の問題(wlan0 IP への ARP に eth0 が応答)は /etc/sysctl.conf を設定して再起動すれば解決すると思います。コメントで整形する方法がわからないのですが、「net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 2」「net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 1」の 2行を追加してください。

Comment: 質問本文に追記した通り、/etc/sysctl.confは変更していないのですが、arpテーブルのキャッシュ削除と再起動で正常化しました。ルーティングテーブルもARPもほとんど知らなかったので、大変有り難いです。

Answer (score 1):

1. RasPiの無線がAPに接続できる
2. Mac -> RasPiに無線経由で送信できる
3. RasPiが受信できる
4. RasPi -> Macに無線経由で送信できる

…という順序で確認していくとして、IPが払い出されているので1.はOKとして、まだ2.が成功していないように見えます。無線に飛ばしたつもりのものが、有線側から届いているので。
<s>Macからルーターまでは無線経路一択だとすると、そこに疑う要素は少なく、ルーターのMacアドレステーブルを疑う手があります。(eth0とwlan0は同じサブネットにあるという設定なら)</s>
↑これはeth0とwlan0とでMacアドレスが異なるので、見当違いです。抹消しておきます。すいません。

全く別の方向性ですが、無線APで無線接続端末間の通信が不可にされているために、うまくいかなかった例もありました。家庭用無線ルーターだとデフォルト許可のような気はしますが、念のため確認すると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確かに現状ではwlan0でのMac->Ras-Piが出来ていません。（ルータ管理画面からのpingは通るのですが、、、）
ご指摘の確認はこれから試させていただきます。

Comment: ああ、Macアドレスは無線と有線で違うので、ルーティングテーブルを疑ったのは筋違いです。すいません。元投稿に抹消線引いておきます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最初の問題の切り分けが甘かったのは確かと思いますので、今後の開発ではご指摘を踏まえて確認するようにします。

Answer (score 0):

/etc/network/interfacesの設定ってどうなっているかって見せてもらうことは可能でしょうか？
何か設定が抜けているような気がします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。設定は質問文に追記させていただきました。何度も書き直したものなので、wlan0に関係ない部分でもRaspbianのデフォルト値からは離れているかもしれません。

Comment: 情報追記ありがとうございます。
wpa_supplicant.confについて記載が足りないような・・・
        proto=WPA
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        group=CCMP
この辺りのパラメーターもいるんじゃなかったかなぁと・・・・
暗号化形式だとかの記載も必要だったはずです。
(自動で認識されたかもですがルーター側が複数の形式を受け入れられる
状況だと明示して記載しないと安定しなかったかと・・・)
ステルスAPをお使いなのでしょうか？
アダプタによってはステルスだと変な挙動をする奴があったかと・・・・

wpa_supplicant.confの切り分けとして
/etc/network/interfacesに直に
wpa-ssid （ルーターのSSID）
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk （ルーターのＰＳＫキー）
を記載してみてどうなるか

よかったら試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えていただいた記述で正しく接続できることを確認しました。記載するファイルが少なくて済むので、今後は教えていただいた記述を使います。